# Can I "Show source of selected element only" on WebStorm, similarly to Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, webstorm

Sometimes I want to toggle between showing the whole file content or just the current function on the JS code editor, similarly to the [Show source of selected element only](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fref-java-editor.htm) feature on Eclipse:

[image]

Is there anything similar to this on WebStorm?